# New Gmail Inbox Actions are shown also in Promotion Tab?

Tags: tabs, gmail, schema

I would like to know if the new functionality of Inbox Actions using Schema will be also shown at Promotion, or Social tabs or only at the Primary Inbox tab?

I mean, if I send a Newsletter including Schema in the HTML code and Gmail identify my newsletters as a Promotion one, will inbox action be also shown? Or only if the newsletter reach the Inbox tab?

Thank you very much in advance!

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a simple test of dragging an email with a GoTo Action button into the Promotions tab, I'd say yes; as the Action button is still visible even when in the Promotions tab.